# Better way to Convert multiple byte Binary to Signed Decimal in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

As I know, it is easy to convert single byte to signed decimal by

```
    char source_binary = '\xff' //-1
    int signedInt = (int)source_binary //signedInt = -1
```

But I would like to know if any better way to handle in multiple byte

```
   //Example -2, represent as 0xFFFE. I got two byte as follow:
   char highByte = '\xff'
   char lowByte = '\xfe'
```

Here is my solution:

```
- (int) convertTwoBytesBinaryToSignedInt:(char)highByte :(char)lowByte
{
    int retValue = 0;
    int hiValue = (int) highByte;
    int loValue = 0;
    if ((int)lowByte < 0)
        loValue = 0 - ((lowByte ^ '\xff') + 1);
    else
        loValue = 0 - 256 + (int)lowByte;

    if (hiValue < 0) {
        //Negative Binary
       retValue = (((hiValue+1)*256)+ loValue);
    } else {
        //Postive Binary
        retValue = ((int)highByte)*256+(int)lowByte;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Would you please advise me any better way to convert it to signed decimal?

Comment: You can represent the hexadecimal number as a character string, then call `strtol()` to turn it into a C long integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int word = ((int) highByte << 8) | (unsigned char) lowByte;
```

EDIT: insufficient testing. :)